# Saving Binary Data FHIR DB

Tags: c#, azure-functions, hl7-fhir

I am trying to save Binary data to FHIR DB.

This is my method:

```
public static Patient SavePdfForms(string resource, HttpClientEventHandler messageHandler, string[] pdfForms, Patient patient, FhirClient BinaryBundleClient)
        {
            Bundle BinaryBundle = new Bundle();
            BinaryBundle.Type = Bundle.BundleType.Collection;
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in pdfForms)
                {
                    Binary BinaryData = new Binary();
                    var bytearray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(item);

                    BinaryData.Data = bytearray;
                    BinaryData.ContentType = "application/fhir+json";
                   
                    var binaryResource = BinaryBundleClient.Create(BinaryData);
                    BinaryBundle.AddResourceEntry(BinaryData, resource + "/BundleResource/" + binaryResource.Id);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            var bundleId = BinaryBundleClient.Create(BinaryBundle);
            patient.Identifier.Add(new Identifier("BinaryBundle", bundleId.Id));
            return BinaryBundleClient.Update(patient);
        }
```

The string[] of pdfForms is base64 and for each form I am creating a new binary and adding data and content type.  But the line `var binaryResource = BinaryBundleClient.Create(BinaryData);` throws an error and data is not a valid json.  I tried with different content type but that is not working. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are creating a new resource instance in `BinaryBundleClient.Create(BinaryData)` and the server to store it.

In your case, you directly pass the binary information in `Fhirclient.Create(your data)`

> binaryResource = **BinaryBundleClient.Create**(BinaryData);

You must mention the type of the **resource instance** which follows:

Create **Fhir client**

```
var client = new FhirClient("http://server.fire.ly");
```

After Creating **FhirClient** You have to create a new `resource instance`. It will be like

```
var pat = new Patient() { /* set up data */ };
var created_pat = client.Create<Patient>(pat);
```

> this interaction will throw an Exception when things go wrong, in most cases a FhirOperationException. This exception has an Outcome property that contains an [OperationOutcome](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/operationoutcome.html) resource, and which you may inspect to find out more information about why the interaction failed. Most FHIR servers will return a human-readable error description in the OperationOutcome to help you out.

Refer [here](https://docs.fire.ly/projects/Firely-NET-SDK/client/crud.html)